# How to run a program at a lower clock speed in C

Tags: c++, c

I need to emulate the workings of a piece of hardware (NOT for video games).

This component runs at 1 Ghz, while my PC's run at 2.5 and 2.7 Ghz.

So I am trying to tell the pc to run this particular process at a lower speed.

I have tried timers, but it won't do: when dealing with small intervals of time the process won't keep track of time with accuracy (I'd need to keep track of milliseconds and it can't be done neatly)
Also to calculate time intervals you would loose some CPU time

Keep in mind that I am not outsourcing to the community, i am working on my own but maybe you guys could help brainstorming :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Which platform BTW ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) is useful for you. Otherwise you might be able to resolve it using a virtual mchine.

Comment: You might try with virtual machines, http://superuser.com/questions/297550/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-machine-in-a-vm. Any way I think your question is offtopic here.

Comment: I work on windows on multiple PC's with different processor speeds. So, although it seems a bice tool the github won't cut it. I have to implement my program on PC's on which i cannot install this tool.

Comment: A timer function won´t be accurate enough, but you can at least get how much time has passed at some point more accurately (QueryPerformanceCounter...). Each timer iteration, calculate how much time has passed since the last iteration and, if necessary, do the work multiple times. About the additional CPU work, you can´t really prevent that on Windows... other processes etc.etc.etc.

Comment: get a modern motherboard with under-clock capability, problem solved, but does your target architecture is same as your PC, which just differ in clock rate? It's not quite compatible with 1GHz ARM vs 1GHz intel, and even intel differ in each generation.

Comment: On Linux, you may be able to set the clock frequency "at will" using the power settings of the CPU itself. However, the actual values you can choose from is typically quite limited - 3 or 4 speeds, and to find one that is exactly 1GHz would require some luck. [AMD processors allow the Power Manager to set the CPU-speed to arbitrary values, but the BIOS typically only has a few speeds listed - so with some programming, you should be able to select different speeds, but it requires that you select the right voltage as well as speed, and not suggested as a first exercise in modifying Linux driver

Comment: I cannot use virtual machines because i have limited ram. The pc itself cannot be downclocked: only this process must be slower

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a piece of hardware doing something at fixed clock of 1GHz? If so, even running your program on a 1GHz clocked CPU would in no way guarantee a fixed 1GHz lockstep for your emulation/simulation.

Comment: Then buying a 1GHz ARM device for about $30 is your only option. No other solution, including a virtual machine, will give you the illusion of running at 1GHz (... and coparable to another platform) when you are running at 2.5GHz. VMs, like timers, are subject to scheduling accuracy and scheduling quanta. You can _at best_ coarsely simulate an approximate _overall_ figure for long, compute-intensive tasks, but that does not at all apply to e.g. responsiveness.

Comment: If the hardware has no inputs, and if you have control over how the outputs are accessed, then it *might* be possible to just let your simulation run as fast as it can until a buffer of outputs is full. Then, the client code could retrieve the output from the buffer for the timestep it expects the simulation to be at. But I'm guessing it's not that simple...

Comment: Guys thanks a lot for all of your inputs. I think my best option as of now is to implement "arbitrary" time delays according to the task appointed.

Comment: @melak47 sorry I just noticed your comment. What I'm trying to do is simulate the workings of a piece of hardware that runs exaclty at 12.5 Hz (i.e. clock count every 80 ms). Again as of now I guess I have to implement timers and make the program wait.

Comment: @Wing You need to emulate a processor of 12.5Hz, and you need to do that using Windows (no linux libs allowed)?

Answer (score 3):

### Premise

From what *I understand from your question & comments*, you need to run a program at a `12.5 Hz` CPU. I can think of single stepping through the instructions, much like a debugger, but instead of waiting for you to single step the instructions, it executes each instruction at every *time delay* (much like what you said you tried). **So, if this premise is wrong, please tell me and I'll delete my answer, cause it's based on it.**

### The Idea

If your clock count is `80ms`, that means you can execute at least one instruction per `80ms`. Unfortunately the [sleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) function will only take `unsigned int` arguments in *seconds*, so that's not gonna work. However, there's the syscall [nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), which lets you adjust a sleep in [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

So, to convert that milliseconds to nano, you multiply it by 10<sup>6</sup>, which will give you `80000000 nanoseconds` of sleep time. As you already mentioned, there will be some time waste from the calling of functions and the emulator time, but I think that's the price you gotta pay for an emulator(and you can always *tinker with the times* to make finer adjustments). So, the `nanosleep` is:

```
#include <time.h>

int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);

struct timespec {
       time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
       long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

The other one is the Linux syscall [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

long ptrace(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid,
               void *addr, void *data);
```

This function will let you do all sorts of things with the traced process, and I suggest you read the manual. It's very informing. That syscall is the base function of debugging software, and you can read a tutorial on [How Debuggers Work](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1/) here.

In fact, my idea came from that tutorial (I read it a couple of days ago), and I'll modify that code a little bit to do the emulator, so I also suggest reading the tutorial.

---

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

#define MILLI       80
#define HZ      ((double)1000/(double)MILLI)

/* milli to nano */
#define m2n(a)      (a*1000*1000) 

void run_target(char *prog)
{
    printf("Emulating %.2lf Hz to proccess %s...\n\n", HZ, prog);

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        return ;
    }

    execl(prog, prog, (char*)NULL);
}

void run_emulator(pid_t child)
{
    int wait_status;
    struct timespec req;
    unsigned long int count = 1;

    /* set up the emulation speed */
    req.tv_sec = 0;
    req.tv_nsec = m2n(MILLI);

    /* wait for stop on first instruction */
    wait(&wait_status);
    while (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) {
        /* this loop will repeat at every instruction, so it executes the
         * instruction and sleeps for the amount of time needed to 
         * emulate the wanted speed.
         */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child, 0, 0) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace");
            return ;
        }
        wait(&wait_status);

        /* this does the sleep */
        nanosleep(&req, NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t child;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [prog_name]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    child = fork();

    if (!child)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child > 0)
        run_emulator(child);
    else {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To make a quick test, I wrote this simple `fat(5)` calculator in Assembly, which has 65 instructions (on my machine, of course):

```
 .section .data
 .section .text
 .globl _start
 .globl factorial
_start:

 pushq  $5
 call   factorial
 movq   %rax, %rdi
 movq   $0x3c, %rax
 syscall

 .type factorial, @function
factorial:
 pushq  %rbp        
 movq   %rsp, %rbp  
 movq   16(%rbp), %rax  
 cmpq   $1, %rax        
 je     end_factorial   
 decq   %rax
 pushq  %rax        
 call   factorial
 movq   16(%rbp), %rbx  
 imulq  %rbx, %rax

end_factorial:
 movq   %rbp, %rsp  
 popq   %rbp
 ret
```

To assemble, link, run and see the result:

```
$ as -o fat.o fat.s
$ ld -o fat fat.o
$ ./fat 
$ echo $?
120
$
```

So, it works and computes the factorial of 5. So, if I'm right on the math, 65 instructions will take `65/12.5` seconds to run on a 12.5Hz CPU, right? `65/12.5 = 5.2`.

```
$ time ./lower ./fat
Emulating 12.50 Hz to proccess ./fat...

Returned: 30720

real    0m5.211s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.008s
```

---

### Manual References

- [wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)
- [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)
- [nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)